# What's the recommended way to make a custom nvd3 build?

Tags: nvd3.js

NVD3 includes a dozen ways of doing charts, and is approx. 500KB before compression. I would like to find ways to trim this file down, specifically because we are only using line and bar charts.

What is the recommended way to build a modular NVD3 library?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific please.

Comment: Added some explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have modified the [grunt file](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/GruntFile.js) commenting out everything that is not needed:

```
src: [
   'src/intro.js',
   'src/core.js',
   'src/interactiveLayer.js',
   'src/tooltip.js',
   'src/utils.js',
   'src/models/axis.js',
   // 'src/models/historicalBar.js',
   // 'src/models/bullet.js',
   // 'src/models/bulletChart.js',
   // 'src/models/cumulativeLineChart.js',
   // 'src/models/discreteBar.js',
   // 'src/models/discreteBarChart.js',
   // 'src/models/distribution.js',
   'src/models/historicalBar.js',
   // 'src/models/historicalBarChart.js',
   // 'src/models/indentedTree.js',
   'src/models/legend.js',
   'src/models/line.js',
   // 'src/models/lineChart.js',
   'src/models/linePlusBarChart.js',
   // 'src/models/lineWithFocusChart.js',
   // 'src/models/linePlusBarWithFocusChart.js',
   // 'src/models/multiBar.js',
   // 'src/models/multiBarChart.js',
   // 'src/models/multiBarHorizontal.js',
   // 'src/models/multiBarHorizontalChart.js',
   // 'src/models/multiChart.js',
   // 'src/models/ohlcBar.js',
   // 'src/models/pie.js',
   // 'src/models/pieChart.js',
   'src/models/scatter.js',
   // 'src/models/scatterChart.js',
   // 'src/models/scatterPlusLineChart.js',
   // 'src/models/sparkline.js',
   // 'src/models/sparklinePlus.js',
   // 'src/models/stackedArea.js',
   // 'src/models/stackedAreaChart.js',
   'src/outro.js'
   ]
```

This works, but a better solution based on modules (browserify, AMD...) would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

So after the v1.8.2 update gruntfile has been changed a little bit. You will not see the list of js files anymore. Instead of it you will see `'src/models/*.js',`

I am creating the custom build following the selected answer. So in order to create it I go through every chart module and note the models they are using. Later I add these `js-files` to `concat.js.src` object in `Gruntfile.js`. Here is an example for most commont LineChart:

```
concat: {
    ...
    js: {
        options: {
            ...
        },
        src: [
        'src/core.js',
        'src/dom.js',
        'src/interactiveLayer.js',
        'src/tooltip.js',
        'src/utils.js',
        //Include all files in src/models
        // 'src/models/*.js',
        // example to exclude files: '!src/models/excludeMe*'
        'src/models/axis.js',
        'src/models/legend.js',
        'src/models/line.js',
        'src/models/lineChart.js',
        'src/models/scatter.js',
        ],
        ...
    }
},
```